# Gradually apply styles ( transitions not seeming to work ) Possibly with js / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to gradually fade in the scroll-bar. Currently, how I am making the scroll-bar appear is by adding a class to the body that changes the overflow to auto, but it looks very jerky / abrupt.

Here is the JS code that abruptly adds the class that shows the scroll-bar:

```
var bodywidth = $('body').width();
var scrollwidth = 10;
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;

    if(x>bodywidth-scrollwidth)
        $('body').addClass("auto");
    else
        $('body').removeClass("auto");
});
```

And here is the CSS corresponding to those clases:

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.auto
{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

How can I make this transition less abrupt? Is there a better way to do it that adding the class and removing the class.

Comment: These are the standard browser scroll bars. As such I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @LeeTaylor okay, thank you. I'll keep the question open, though.

Answer (score 2):

The scrollbars can be customized via -webkit-scrollbar, but this can not be animated (or at least I didn't succeded at it), and support in other browser is poor.

An alternative is to set a div just over the scrollbar, make it the same color than the base div, and make it gradually transparent to show the scrollbar

the html is:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="base">
<p>aaa   aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaa bbbbbb bbbbbb cccc cccc cccc
</p>
</div>
<div class="hide">
</div>
</div>
```

the CSS is:

```
.base {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.base.clipped {
    overflow: auto;
}


.hide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 19px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    z-index: 10;
}

.hide.clipped {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I am keeping the class of the elements all the time, but adding a second class clipped to both. I set a padding in the element that will have the scrollbars so that there space for it without rearranging the layout. The hide element can be transitioned with css, the overflow not.

the javascript is

```
$("*").click(function(){
    var obj = $(".base");
    var hid = $(".hide");
    if (obj.hasClass("clipped")) {
        hid.removeClass("clipped");
        setTimeout(function() {
            obj.removeClass("clipped");
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        hid.addClass("clipped");
        obj.addClass('clipped');
    }
 });
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/GE8BC/)